# How to have a text or an image appear on some part of web page on hovering top or bottom half of a sliding image in an image slider?

Tags: css, image-processing

I am just a noob and want to ask that in my centralized image slider, I want that some image or text to appear to the right or some palce in my web page based on top or bottom half of the sliding image being hovered. Please, tell me how to do that ?

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. I really can't make sense of what you are asking. Would you care to explain in more detail or perhaps make a quick sketch if it's hard to explain with words?

Comment: I am saying I have got an image slider having 5 images. I want that if I click on top half or bottom half of the image - different events must occur; for example on top right of my page a new image must appear if I click pic 1/5 of my image slider.